# Get IDs from select and use them in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a select box, like so:

```
 <select id="school">
   <option>Choose school</option>
   <option value="656462">test</option>
   <option value="653671">test1</option>
   <option value="653688">test2</option>        
 </select>
```

How do I get the option values from the above options? I want to use the values in the below jQuery code:

```
 $("select#school").change(function(){

    $("select#locatie").html('<option value="">Course</option>');
    $("select#lijst").html('<option value="">List</option>');

    $("#cat1").html($("#school option:selected").text());
    $("#cat2").html('Course');
    $("#cat3").html('List');

    var options = '';
    $(function(){
      $("select#school").change(function(){

        $("select#location").html('<option value="">Location</option>');
        $("select#list").html('<option value="">List</option>');

        $("#cat1").html($("#school option:selected").text());
        $("#cat2").html('Course');
        $("#cat3").html('List');

        var options = '';


        if($("#school").val() == 656462){   
            options += '<option value="">Course</option>';
            options += '<option value="12345">test1</option>';   
        }  
        if($("#school").val() == 653671){   
            options += '<option value="">Course</option>';
            options += '<option value="89887">test2</option>';   
        }
        if($("#school").val() == 653688){   
            options += '<option value="">Course</option>';
            options += '<option value="548798">test25</option>';   
        }              

        $("select#locatie").html(options);

  });
});
```

Basically, for every option value there's a new if statement. Problem is that the selectbox is filled with a lot of option values which are generated automatically. So now I have to do everything by hand instead of automatically generated if statements.

So what I try to do is:
1) get all the option values from the 
2) use these option values to create an if statement for every value

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: "this needs to be one of the above values" --  what above values? `this.value` inside the `change` will give you the selected value. Then what?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do cascading selects. Can you provide more markup?

Comment: @tymeJV: I've updated the question and markup

Comment: Why don't you stick the possible options into a dictionary kind of array and get rid of all those ifs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to create new options for a second select based on the results of the first? I'd probably store the possible options in an array on an object:

```
var courseSelection = {
    "656462": [ { value: "123456", text: "Course 1" }, { value: "234567", text: "Course 2" } ],
    "653671": [ { value: "345678", text: "Course 3" }, { value: "456789", text: "Course 4" } ],
    "653688": [ { value: "567890", text: "Course 5" }, { value: "678901", text: "Course 6" } ]
};
```

And then in your change event handler, (as you state) you can loop through each object in the array to build the appropriate list:

```
$("select#school").change(function(){

    var options = '',
        courses = courseSelection[$(this).val()];

    $('select#course').empty();

    options += '<option value="">Course</option>';

    $.each(courses, function() {
        options += '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.text + '</option>';
     });

    $('select#course').append(options).show();

});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LgtA9/2/) describing what I mean. Let me know if I've got the wrong end of the stick here!

Comment: .append would likely work better for the options, or appendTo - if not, the first .html(<... course ...) is not useful

Comment: Good point well made, @mplungjan. I've updated to use append and of course ensured the `select` box is `empty()` before updating ;)

Comment: @SimonAdcock: Thx for your explaination. I understand what you do... You're almost on the right end ;) The only problem with your code is that all values in the 'select#school' or in your array need to come from the actual selectbox on top of this page (above jquery code). So how can I fill your array automatically instead of filling in the possibillities by hand?

Comment: Ah, I see, well therein lies the problem! You need a way of mapping the values held in your schools select box with the course arrays. How to do that with doing it by hand? You say the list of schools could be quite long, suggesting it is held in a table on a database somewhere? Would it not be easier (and notably faster!) to do the mapping on the database and use the front end to just display the results? i.e. convert the logic in your `if` statements into a query that returns the necessary courses.

Comment: @SimonAdcock: Thank you for helping. I've managed to get it to work. The mapping is done in a db and with your script I'm able to do the magic. +1

Answer (score 0):

Re-think your approach. In this case, I'll do one of the following:

1. On the #school `change` event send the selected value to the server to get the list of matching options; or
2. If you want to do it all on the client side, create an array that for each possible value, gives matching options. This way you can avoid all this ugly `if` statements.